# I have node.js application I am setting .env using dotenv, I get the following error when using port

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I have node.js application I have installed dotenv and add the following configuration in my .env file

```
 DB_HOST='localhost'
 DB_Database=TheDatabasename
 DB_USER=TheUser
 DB_PASS=thePassword
 DB_PORT=1433
```

I am using sqlserver I call dotenv like bellow:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const config = {
 user: process.env.DB_USER,
 password: process.env.DB_PASS,
 server: process.env.DB_HOST, 
 database: process.env.DB_Database,
 port: process.env.DB_PORT,
}

 const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
.connect()
.then(pool => {
 console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
 return pool
})
 .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))

 module.exports = {
  sql, poolPromise
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
  Database Connection Failed! Bad Config:  TypeError: The "config.options.port" property must be of type number.
```

Comment: Try `port : parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT);`

Comment: When you read from your .env file, the values are returned as string. You need to parse them to appropriate types (in this case, integer) - parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mssql, require a type number in the port parameter and the environment variables are string.

You should cast the value before sent to the driver

```
...
 port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
...
```

Comment: How to do this in typescript? When I try to run the code it throws "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

Comment: I think you should use a fallback...
`parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT || "", 10) `

Answer (score 2):

All Environment Variables are STRINGS, So just convert the port to INT.

```
const config = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  server: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
    trustedServerCertificate: false,
  },
};
```