# The "config.options.port" property must be of type number - ENV

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am using TypeORM as orm for my express application. I want to use the ENV variable to set the host, posrt, username, password etc. for the `ormconfig` file.
However I get as error:

> TypeError: The "config.options.port" property must be of type number.

My `ormconfig.js` file looks like:

```
export default {
  "type": process.env.TYPEORM_CONNECTION,
  "host": process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  "port": parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT, 10), <-- I DO cast it as INTEGER
  "username": process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  "password": process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  "database": process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  ...
}
```

My `.env` looks like:

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION=mssql
TYPEORM_HOST=my_host
TYPEORM_PORT=1433
TYPEORM_USERNAME=my_username
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=my_password
TYPEORM_DATABASE=my_database
```

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699790/i-have-node-js-application-i-am-setting-env-using-dotenv-i-get-the-following-e) solution did **not** work for me

Comment: Did you `require("dotenv")` and call `dotenv.config();`?

Comment: @D.Pardal I have not. However, it seems that updating TypeORM to the latest version (`0.2.31`) solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that updating TypeORM to a latest version solved the problem.
In my case, I moved from version `0.2.21` to version `0.2.31`